# How to make Checklist Items on Mediawiki?

Tags: checkbox, mediawiki

Hello I am using a Mediawiki install on my dev server, just to organize my thoughts, write documentation for my apps, make note files/pages for general topics for easy reference, and so much more.  A personal wiki can be so useful for programmers/coders/etc..

I have a wiki page that is a To-Do list for a project with multiple items, it would be really awesome if there was a way to add checkboxes next to my list items in mediawiki, and then upon checking them, either make the item striked through (line through it) or make the check box remain checked, upon revisiting the page at later dates.

Does anyone know if there is a Plugin for media wiki that does this or something like this?  Or if it is even possible to do something like this with  just a plugin?

Please any ideas or suggestions on how to accomplish this or similar capability with a media wiki install (same code used for wikipedia)

Thanks for help, ideas, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would need to install [Extension:Widgets](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWidgets).  Then, you can install the [Google Gadget Widget](http://www.mediawikiwidgets.org/Widget%3aGoogle_Gadget).  Then, you can lastly pick from your choice of to-do list type gadgets [here](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&hl=&gl=&q=todo).

Comment: But how is each wiki page associated with a _different_ todo list? And where does the todo list get stored?

Comment: Broken links, and login required.

Comment: To be fair, 8+ years ago when I answered this, it all worked...

Answer (score 1):

This renders a nice list of checkboxes:

```
== My Wiki Header ==

Here's an example checklist:
<html>
<input type="checkbox"> Item A.<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Item B.<br>
<input type="checkbox"> Item C.<br>
</html>
```

Of course the checkboxes won't do anything, they're just for the looks.